# jQuery - hover function with two classes for an element, a hover for each class

Tags: jquery

I'm not sure if this is a different problem embedded somewhere in my code, or an issue with the hover function i'm not aware of -

in short, i have an element with two classes

```
<input type="image" class="classA classB" ... />
```

and i have jQuery code like so:

```
$('classA').hover(){
    function1,
    function2
}

$('classB').hover(){
    function3,
    function4
}
```

what i'm wanting is that when you hover over the input, BOTH hover functions (function1, function3) get fired. And when you move off it, BOTH functions (function2, function4) are also fired.
What appears to be happening is that the classB hover completely overrides or shadows or what have you the classA hover function.

Is this intended behaviour (or is this an indication that something is wrong with my much-larger code base?), and if so, what is the general consensus work around?

Comment: no. The real code is a bit more complicated, I was mostly wondering if *i* had done a problem, or if that was hover's expected operation. Also if there was a simple way to, i dunno "join" hovers or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AH-HA!

Ok, so sp00m's answer here were good and right - but it wasn't *quite* for my purpose. Because i have a fair bit of code running around, I was hoping to keep things "clean" (cleanish?). I probably should have been clearer in the original question...

See, I already had elements that needed the first hover, and elements that needed the second, so when i had elements that needed *both* the aim was to not have a *third* hover for that scenario. Code non-reuse and complexity! Boo!

What I didn't realise was that the hover that comes last will overwrite the first hover. This is probably something to do with the fact that it was targeting one class, and the first was targeting another.

The solution was this:

```
$('.classB, .classA').hover(){
    function3,
    function4
}
```

Happily, when i target classA using the multi selector it *doesn't* override the original hover.

That is, I removed classB from the class attribute for my input, and added classA to the hover selector!

Answer (score 3):

The `classB`'s hover overwrites the `classA`'s hover in the case of a tag that has both classes, because of the order they are written in (`classB`'s hover after `classA`'s hover).

A solution could be:

```
$('.classA, .classB').hover(
// mouseover
function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.hasClass('classA')) {
        function1();
    }
    if($this.hasClass('classB')) {
        function3();
    }

},
// mouseout
function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.hasClass('classA')) {
        function2();
    }
    if($this.hasClass('classB')) {
        function4();
    }
});
```

Comment: This code doesn't make sense. Both conditions valuate to true.

Comment: @undefined Yeah, so both of the `if` will return true, and that's what the OP wanted, am I wrong?

Comment: as I read OP function1 and function3 should fire when you hover and function2 and function4 shoould fire when you move off. Yours will fire all functions on hover for those elements that have both classes want it?